# How to fix breaking changes with flyway?

Tags: mysql, compatibility, flyway

I have a mysql database.
In one of the earliest schema versions there was a script that created a table with a null primary key (yes this was a bug in MySql <= version 5.6)

When upgrading the server to mysql57 the migration stops at this point and cannot continue because of migration script itself is not compatible anymore.

I mean, I cannot fix the migration script schema v3 when we are in v11 now, and it has a checksum also.

How do you handle this kind of situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that one possible solution is to modify old migration script and then call [repair](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/repair) before migration to correct checksums.

Comment: Thank you!
That is exactly I was looking for.